# Why does Math.Pow(x,y) using double instead of long?

Tags: java, pow

We need to use *long* and *Long.toUnsignedString()* as type for the rice but ***Math.Power*** is changing it to **double**:

```
package com.company;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int rk = 0;

        for (byte feld = 1; feld < 65; feld++) {
            System.out.println("Feld: " + feld + ", Reiskörner: " + Math.pow(2, rk));
            rk = rk+1;
        }
    }
}
```

I tested many things but nothing worked.
The Output is:

```
Feld: 1, Reiskörner: 1.0
Feld: 2, Reiskörner: 2.0
Feld: 3, Reiskörner: 4.0
...
Feld: 63, Reiskörner: 4.6116860184273879E18
Feld: 64, Reiskörner: 9.223372036854776E18
```

insted of:

```
Feld: 1, Reiskörner: 1
Feld: 2, Reiskörner: 2
...
```

Comment: Well you can just use typecasting ...?

Comment: wrap it if you don't like `double`

Comment: Use `1L << rk` instead of `Math.pow(2, rk)`, at least for `rk` in the range [0, 62].  It's much more efficient, and the result is already a `long`.  For `rk` outside that range, the mathematical result is not representable by type `long` (so using `pow()` and converting the result to `long` is no better).  For `rk` of 63 the shift will produce a large negative number, and for larger or negative `rk` it will produce 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily cast back to `long`:

```
System.out.println("Feld: " + feld + ", Reiskörner: " + (long) Math.pow(2, rk));
```

But you should note that `Math.pow(2,63)` is too large to fit in a long variable.

The max `long` value is 2<sup>63</sup>-1.

You can also avoid `Math.pow()` if you use the shift operator:

```
System.out.println("Feld: " + feld + ", Reiskörner: " + Long.toUnsignedString ((1L << rk)));
```

Note that I used `Long.toUnsignedString` in order to correctly print 2<sup>63</sup>.

Comment: Now it is working but how do i use Long.toUnsignedString() for bigger numbers

Answer (score 0):

It is inefficient to call Math.pow() so many times in a loop when all you need to do is multiply by two each time:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long rk = 1;

    for (byte feld = 1; feld < 65; feld++) {
        System.out.println("Feld: " + feld + ", Reiskörner: " + Long.toUnsignedString(rk));
        rk *= 2;
    }
}
```

This also works with long negative numbers (printed as unsigned), such as you get when the result is too large to fit in a signed long, because the multiplication works as expected, unlike casting from a double.

Comment: why not join the shifting trend with `rk<<=1`

Comment: @fantaghirocco because `rk<<=2` does not mean `rk *= 2`. You probably meant `rk <<= 1;` but the fact you got it wrong demonstrates how easy it is to get things like this wrong when you are trying to model a real-world problem (something doubling in size) by using computer-specific things (bit shifting). Best to keep the solution as close as possible to the problem: less chance of errors. Edit: I just saw that you corrected it while I was replying. My reply still stands.